# Linear convergence of a series such that $u_{n+k} \le \frac{\alpha}{k} u_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have a series $u_n$ that satisfies the following property, for some $\alpha>0$ and for all $n,k > 0$:
$$0 \le u_{n+k} \le \frac{\alpha}{k} u_n.$$

This implies that $u_{n+\lceil \frac{2}{\alpha}\rceil} \le \frac{1}{2} u_n$, which, applied recursively, gives $u_{T\lceil \frac{2}{\alpha}\rceil} \le \frac{1}{2^T} u_0$. Hence $u_n$ converges linearly to zero, but I can't prove it for any value of $n$.

Intuitively, I would say that you could prove some upper bound along the line of $u_n \le \exp(-\beta n) u_0$ for some $\beta$. Is there such a closed-form upper bound on the series $u_n$?